# Chart.js bar graph isn't displaying the correct information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, chart.js

I'm working on a simple budget tracking app and one of my graphs isn't updating correctly. I'm trying to display initial income alongside actual income, which is income - expenses. I must be missing something important because my income - expenses simply isn't showing up. for example, i will set my initial income at 5,000 and then create an expense of 1,000. My bar graph will still only display that initial income of 5,000. I also have a pie chart set up to show the user their expense categories, and that is correctly connected to each expense that I create, so I'm not sure where the breakdown is happening.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Pie, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import './Analytics.css';

const electron = window.require('electron');
const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;

const Analytics = () => {
  const [expenseCategoryData, setExpenseCategoryData] = useState(null);
  const [monthlyIncomeData, setMonthlyIncomeData] = useState(null);
  const [incomeData, setIncomeData] = useState(new Array(12).fill(0));
  const [expensesData, setExpensesData] = useState(new Array(12).fill(0));
  const actualIncomeData = incomeData.map((income, index) => income - expensesData[index])

  const backgroundColors = [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    // Request expense category data
    ipcRenderer.send('request-expense-category-data');

    // Request monthly income and expenses data
    ipcRenderer.send('request-monthly-income-data');
    ipcRenderer.send('request-monthly-expenses-data');

    ipcRenderer.on('expense-category-data-response', (event, data) => {
      const totalExpense = data.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.total, 0);
      const formattedData = {
        labels: data.map(item => item.category),
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Expenses by Category',
          data: data.map(item => item.total),
          backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
        }]
      };
      setExpenseCategoryData(formattedData);
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('monthly-income-data-response', (event, newData) => {
      const newIncomeData = new Array(12).fill(0);
      newData.forEach(item => {
        const monthIndex = parseInt(item.month, 10) - 1;
        newIncomeData[monthIndex] = item.total;
      });
      setIncomeData(newIncomeData);
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('monthly-expenses-data-response', (event, newData) => {
      const newExpensesData = new Array(12).fill(0);
      newData.forEach(item => {
        const monthIndex = parseInt(item.month, 10) - 1;
        newExpensesData[monthIndex] = item.total;
      });
      setExpensesData(newExpensesData);
    });

    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('expense-category-data-response');
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('monthly-income-data-response');
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('monthly-expenses-data-response');
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const actualIncomeData = incomeData.map((income, index) => income - expensesData[index]);
  
    setMonthlyIncomeData({
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Income Before Expenses',
          data: incomeData,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
        },
        {
          label: 'Actual Income',
          data: actualIncomeData,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        }
      ]
    });
  }, [incomeData, expensesData]); 
  

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Monthly Income Analysis'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: false,
      }
    }
  };

  

  return (
    <div>
      {expenseCategoryData && (
        <div className='chart-container'>
          <h2>Expenses by Category</h2>
          <Pie
            key={Date.now()}
            data={expenseCategoryData}
            options={{ animation: { duration: 2000, loop: false } }}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      {monthlyIncomeData && (
        <div className='chart-container'>
          <h2>Monthly Income Analysis</h2>
          <Bar data={monthlyIncomeData} options={options} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Analytics;
```

Comment: Possibly the mapping of your actual income is not completing before the chart data is set? Have you tried creating a manual array of numbers to see if that shows successfully?